# Zigzag Iterator

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x, iterator

I've recently solved the LeetCode's "ZigZag iterator" problem:

> Given two 1d vectors, implement an iterator to return their elements
> alternately.
>
> For example, given two 1d vectors:
>
> ```
> v1 = [1, 2] 
> v2 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
> ```
>
> By calling next repeatedly until `hasNext` returns false, the order of elements returned by next should be:
>
> ```
> [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
> ```

Note that there is a pre-defined `ZigzagIterator` class definition contract that requires to implement `__init__()`, `next()` and `hasNext()` methods.

---

The idea behind the below implementation was to make it work for any number of potential input iterators that need to be iterated in a "zigzag" fashion. That's why I used the `izip_longest()` and `chain()`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain


class ZigzagIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, *iterators):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        :type v1: List[int]
        :type v2: List[int]
        """
        self.iterators = chain(*izip_longest(*iterators))

    def next(self):
        """
        :rtype: int
        """
        result = next(self.iterators)
        return self.next() if result is None else result

    def hasNext(self):
        """
        :rtype: bool
        """
        try:
            peek = self.next()
            self.iterators = chain(iter([peek]), self.iterators)
            return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False
```

This works and passes the LeetCode's OJ tests, but I'm not quite happy with the solution regarding handling the `None` values created by `izip_longest()` and peeking into the next value by advancing the iterator and creating a new one, "pre-pending" the peeked value.

What would you improve in the presented code? Is there a better, more optimal approach?

---

FYI, here is a sample `ZigzagIterator` usage:

```
v1 = iter([1, 2])
v2 = iter([3, 4, 5, 6])
i, v = ZigzagIterator(v1, v2), []
while i.hasNext():
    v.append(i.next())
print(v)  # prints [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Not an answer, as it's 'incorrect', but I'd personally use the `roundrobin` function from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recursion in your `next()` method is bizarre:

> ```
> return self.next() if result is None …
> ```

I would just let it fail with a `StopIteration`.

Furthermore, I would avoid having `hasNext()` call `self.next()`, as the whole point of `hasNext()` is to determine whether it is "safe" to call `self.next()`.

I don't think you need to call `iter(…)` explicitly within `hasNext()`.

With those remarks, and a few minor simplifications:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain

class ZigzagIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, *iterators):
        self.iter = chain(*izip_longest(*iterators))

    def hasNext(self):
        try:
            self.iter = chain([next(self.iter)], self.iter)
            return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False

    def next(self):
        return next(self.iter)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem on LeetCode says you should implement `hasNext` and `next` but this is not usually how it is done in Python. I would consider that you revise your code to implement `next` (and when you decide to use Python 3, `__next__`) and `__iter__`. Typically the method `hasNext` is merged with `next`. You can see a [few examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19151/667648):

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.current = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self): # Python 3: def __next__(self)
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current - 1


for c in Counter(3, 8):
    print c
```

([copied from the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377/667648))

For the learning experience, instead of giving you the code, I'll leave it for you to re-implement.